# Application restarts while navigating back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, back-stack

See I have 3 activities, `A`, `B` and `C`. I go to activity `C` from `A`.

A -> B -> C

While in activity `C`, press home button and leave it for some long time. When I bring application back to foreground after some long inactivity either from application back stack or from launcher icon, I land on activity `C`. Now, while in activity `C`, if I press back button or click back navigation arrow from action bar, application restarts and starts activity `A` instead of resuming activity `B`.

What could possibly cause this behaviour?

Comment: I think you are finishing the activity C somewhere in between check your code if you have called `finish()`

Comment: @AkshayKatariya Nope. Nowhere I am calling finish and all are simple and plain startActivity calls without any flags. BTW, how does finishing activity C can cause this behaviour?

Comment: Did you finish Activity B before you call Activity C?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you doing like this or not

```
 <activity
        android:name=".C"    
        android:parentActivityName=".B">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".B" />
  </activity>
```